# RAID 5 disk failure?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, storage

I know theoretically how RAID 5 works. In one of my system one disk failure happened on a system with RAID 5. It will take a day to get it replaced.
I understand once disk is replace, data will be reconstructed with parity concept and no data lost will happen.

My question is till disk is not replaced will there be any impact on the system ?  Per my understanding yes there will be impact. Reason: Say File_A has
two blocks block_1 and block_2 where block_1 was written on disk_1 and block_2 was written on disk_2, disk_3 writes the parity bits. now disk_2 is gone,
till it is replaced will I be able to read File_A. I believe no ? Is that correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will still be able to read file A.  The RAID controller will reconstruct the data on the fly when you ask for it, in exactly the same way that it will reconstruct the data when it rebuilds disk 1.  Depending on the specific implementation there might be some loss of performance until disk 1 has been replaced and rebuilt.

There is also some risk of another disk failing before disk 1 has finished rebuilding, particularly if all the disks are the same age and model.  If this happens, all the data in the RAID 5 array is lost.  For that reason RAID 5 is no longer considered best practice; you should use RAID 6 if possible.

Comment: Using RAID6 vs RAID5 is more of a statistical thing. As disk sizes have increased, their chance of 'unrecoverable read error' has not. One error every 12 TB is no problem with 80 GB disks, but today, it is.

Comment: RAID6 "offer" 2 failed disks which is still more than 1 in case of RAID5. Independently on disk size if possible it is for sure better way to go ;-).